# How could I do a special round corner shape for ImageView/FrameLayout?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, rounded-corners, android-framelayout

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277151/framelayout-with-rounded-corners-but-also-no-edges) I try to make round corners for my FrameLayout.
Here is my rounded_shape.xml shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/margin"
            android:color="@color/colorBackground"/>
    <corners android:radius="24dp" />
</shape>
```

which looks then so:
[rounded_shape.xml Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xns6S.png)

When I do in my code:
frameLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapPhoto.bitmap));  frameLayout.setForeground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_shape));
it will look like this:
[result on app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9TIQ.png)

You can see the black edges through the rounded corners.

**How can I do a shape like this:
[where the the edges are rounded and the black parts are gone already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk3O9.png)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two shapes parallel.

- One shape with round corners, doing the inner corner round.
- One shape with pointed corners, doing the outer corner sharp

All structed in a `layer-list` as you can see in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/margin"
                android:color="@color/color" />
            <corners android:radius="24dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/margin"
                android:color="@color/color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```